# Selenium - when exactly the webdriver instance gets updated?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to automate a task on a very dynamic website with pyhton.
For this reason certain HTML elements of the current loaded page may or may not be present at the moment of the request from my code.
How exactly the webdriver instance gets updated and receives the new data from the web page?

Is it constantly connected and receive the change in the HTML code instantly?

Or it first download a first verion of the page when `driver.get()` is called, and then updates it whenever a function such as `.find_element_by_class_name()` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q. Is it constantly connected and receives the change in the HTML code instantly?

Ans. Well, for each `Selenium command`, there will be an `HTTP request` that will `send to the browser driver` and then to the server and the command will get, A HTTP response will be returned and the command/commands will get executed based on the response.

Now let's say in a situation you do,

```
driver.get()
```

Basically, this is a selenium command.

It would fire `an HTTP request` stating to launch the `URL provided`. Based on the `response (200-Ok or anything else)`, you would either see the WebPage getting loaded or an error message.

Same way in Sequence all the Selenium commands will get executed.

It's obvious that we need locators to locate web elements in the UI.

Once we have them, we can tightly couple them with

```
driver.find_element_by_***
```

methods.

Things to be noted down here

You need to learn/understand :

1. Implicit Waits.
2. Explicit Waits.
3. Fluent Waits.

**Implicit Waits :**

By implicitly waiting, `WebDriver polls the DOM for a certain duration` when trying to find any element. This can be useful when certain elements on the webpage are not available immediately and need some time to load.

Basically what it means is, whenever you use `drive.find_element` it gonna look for implicit waits if you have defined one.

If you've not defined one implicit wait, then the default value is 0.

**Explicit wait**

They allow your c`ode to halt program execution`, or `freeze the thread`, until the condition you pass it resolves. The condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the `condition returns a falsy value`, it will keep trying and waiting.

**FluentWait**

FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition.

Reference [Link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

**Updated :**

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Locators (by priority from top):**

1. **ID**
2. **name**
3. **classname**
4. **linkText**
5. **partialLinkText**
6. **tagName**
7. **css selector**
8. **xpath**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but just to be clear, the HTTP request is sent also for each find_element_by_***? If this is the case I don't get why if I load the page, pause the code and manually navigate to another page, and resume the code it won't find any element of the new page

Comment: the HTTP request is sent also for each find_element_by_***? - Yes this is true. for the case that you've mentioned, it when you navigate to other page, locators may have been changed and that is the reason it won't find any element on the new page. Let me update the answer on how to check for locators in Selenium

Comment: Thank you, this was my question, I asked it because sometimes it happens that I don't find the element I want even though it is clearly present on the screen and I thought that maybe I was not understanding how Selenium works

Answer (score 1):

Web page is loaded by `driver.get()`.
But the driver doesn't "know" what elements are existing there. It just opens, loads the web page.
To access any element, to check element presence etc. you will need to do that particularly per each specific element / elements using commands like `.find_element_by_class_name()` with a specific element locator.